# What happens to written WAL logs if a transaction is aborted in the middle?

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging

I was thinking about scenario below.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT SOMETHING;
INSERT SOMETHING;
##CLIENT COMPUTER EXPLODES
```

If i understand correctly, after each INSERT statement, a log entry is written to WAL of the database server.

In this scenario there are now 2 new lines in WAL, but a COMMIT statement will never get executed because client computer exploded. So what will happen to 2 lines written into WAL?
Will they be deleted after connection lost?
Will they be kept forever as remains of an incomplete transaction?
Will an ABORT statement get inserted into WAL after client disconnects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WAL records remain; WAL is never modified retroactively. They will be replayed during recovery, but since there is no `COMMIT` records for that transaction in the WAL, they will remain invisible.